# C# permite propriedade genérica em uma classe?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, classes, genéricos

Tenho uma classe com duas propriedades (`Name` e `Value`). A propriedade `Name` é uma `string`, já a propriedade `Value` quero deixar o tipo variável.

```
public class Field<TValue>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public Field()
    {
    }

    public Field(string name, TValue value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Nesse caso seria simples instanciar essa classe com o tipo desejado:

```
var field1 = new Field<int>("Nome1", 1);
var field2 = new Field<string>("Nome2", "Valor2");
```

O problema é que tenho uma classe intermediária que usa a classe `Field` como propriedade:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public Field<TValue>[] FieldArray { get; set; }
}
```

Ou seja, quero poder ter um `array` de *Field's* genéricos, mas este último exemplo não é válido para o compilador.

Meu objetivo final é algo parecido com isso:

```
var myClassObject = new MyClass();
myClassObject.Prop1 = "Teste";
myClassObject.Prop2 = 10;

myClassObject.FieldArray = new Field<TValue>[10];

myClassObject.FieldArray[0] = new Field<string>();
myClassObject.FieldArray[0].Name = "Field1";
myClassObject.FieldArray[0].Value = "Value1";

myClassObject.FieldArray[1] = new Field<int>();
myClassObject.FieldArray[1].Name = "Field2";
myClassObject.FieldArray[1].Value = 2;
```

A linguagem permite fazer algo do tipo? Qual seria a forma correta?

Comment: Ao invés de `TValue`, não seria melhor usar `object`?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar não. nunca.

Comment: Queria poder forçar uma tipagem mais forte. Acho o `object` muito subjetivo, mas acredito que vai ser o jeito...

Comment: Eu entendo você querer, o tipo fortemente tipado, o problema é que tu quer varia esse tipo dentro de um array e isso que é problemático. Claro que isso vai exigir alguma complexidade maior no tratamento dos tipos, mas, imagino eu, que dentro de um array não seja viável...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Você quer a mesma instância de `MyClass` tenha arrays de `Field` com tipos diferentes?

Comment: Exatamente @LINQ ! Será que é possível?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Eu não sou um grande entendedor de C#, mas eu acho que isso não é possível (pelo menos não da forma que você pensou) porque os tipos precisam ser conhecidos em tempo de compilação e esta dinamicidade que você precisa não permite isto.

Comment: @LINQ ainda assim agradeço muito sua colaboração, acredito que terei de usar `object` como o @FelipeAvelar comentou.

Comment: Só um pitaco: entre `object` e `dynamic` eu iria de `object`, @JedaiasRodrigues

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No caso de ter uma propriedade ou qualquer variável que precisa ter tipos diferentes, não tem como manter a tipagem estática e a genericidade não cabe neste caso, a não ser que pelo menos possa restringir um pouco, então se pode variar, mas sempre em cima de um tipo comum específico, já dá para fazer algo.

Como parece que pode qualquer situação, tem que usar `dynamic`, achei o mais adequado para o caso, mas pode ser que não dependendo do contexto, ou `object`.

Precisa analisar se precisa disto mesmo. Muitas vezes o programador acha que precisa, mas pode ter outra solução.

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var myClassObject = new MyClass() { Prop1 = "Teste", Prop2 = 10, FieldArray = new Field<dynamic>[2] { new Field<dynamic>("f1", "v1"), new Field<dynamic>("f1", 1) } };
    }
}

public class Field<TValue> {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public Field() {}

    public Field(string name, TValue value) {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public Field<dynamic>[] FieldArray { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RyxN8e). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nOC66T). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Dynamic/PropertyVariable.cs).

Comment: Um pequeno adendo: Em vez de usar essa classe `Field`, o OP pode usar `KeyValuePair<string, object>`, que já existe no framework.

Answer (score 8):

Baseado nessa resposta do [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606974/1606920), você precisa ter um tipo base comum para poder "estender" esses objetos em coleções. No caso de `string`e `int`, o tipo base comum será, justamente, o `object`.

Então o seu código ficaria dessa forma

```
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public Field()
    {
    }

    public Field(string name, object value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

e a classe com o Field:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public Field[] FieldArray { get; set; }
}
```

Isso deve resolver o seu problema e, caso necessário, sempre é possível fazer o tratamento para tornar o `Value` fortemente tipado.

Answer (score 6):

O que você requisitou pode ser feito com `dynamic` ou `object`.

**Exemplo:**

```
public class Field<TValue>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    public Field()
    {
    }

    public Field(string name, TValue value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public int Prop2 { get; set; }

    public Field<dynamic>[] FieldArray { get; set; }
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
    var x = new MyClass();
    x.FieldArray = new Field<dynamic>[5];

    x.FieldArray[0] = new Field<dynamic>();
    x.FieldArray[0].Value = "Teste";

    x.FieldArray[1] = new Field<dynamic>();
    x.FieldArray[1].Value = 1;
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/99Byzn)

Comment: Por que só pode ser feito com dynamic? `object` não funciona pra este caso?

Comment: Funciona, adicionei a opção. Obrigado.

Comment: De nada, fica meu voto positivo agora