# Obter conteúdo de objeto sem saber o nome do atributo

Tags: c#, .net, objetos, tipagem

Em JavaScript tenho, por exemplo, o objeto:

```
var meuCarro = {
    fabricacao: "Ford",
    modelo: "Mustang",
    ano: 1969
};
```

E para acessar o conteúdo dele, quando eu não souber o nome do atributo, posso acessar desta forma:

```
var atributo = "modelo"; //o nome do atributo obtenho via run time
var conteudo = meuCarro[atributo];
```

Como posso fazer isso em C#? A única forma que conheço nessa linguagem é, por exemplo, `string conteudo = meuCarro.modelo`, mas não consigo resolver meu problema assim porque obtenho o nome do atributo em *run time*.

Comment: Você irá criar um atributo em run time e depois pegar o valor dele?

Comment: @Barbetta, não... Os nomes dos atributos estarão armazenados num array que foi criado em design time. Em run time, através do índice do array seleciono dele uma string com o nome do atributo desejado e "printo" na tela o conteúdo.

Comment: Outra forma de eu conseguir resolver meu problema é através de if ou case pra cada atributo, mas o código ficaria muito extenso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você já tem a classe e não sabe nada sobre ela, e é totalmente dinâmico, realmente deve usar reflexão, assim pode usar variáveis no lugar do nome. Tem um [exemplo complexo em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105236/101).

Se você vai criar o objeto e quer a mesma semântica do JavaScript deve usar um dicionário no lugar de uma classe, afinal no JS o objeto na verdade é um dicionário. [Já respondi com um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92090/101). Na verdade, em [vários exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257902/101).

Se você não sabe o que vai acessar então deve usar `dynamic`, mas deve evitar sempre que possível porque [C# não é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203656/101). [Exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68085/101).

[Uma última solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241121/101). Claro, tem soluções ainda mais complicadas.

Pelos comentários eu iria de `switch`, código extenso não é justificativa para usar reflexão, o código fica absurdamente mais lento. Se não quer escrever o código escreva um gerador de código, C# tem cada vez mais ferramentas para auxiliar nisso (na 9 ou 10 terá recursos bem interessantes). Mas se ainda insistir em não escrever o código puro, pelo menos considere o uso de um dicionário, pela descrição da pergunta e comentários é o que precisa. Quase sempre reflexão é gambiarra.

Uma última dica: [o que você quer é um campo e não o atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101), eu sei que te ensinaram assim, mas ensinaram errado, use a terminologia correta para evitar confusão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `Reflection` para pegar a lista de todos atributos do objeto e depois com `linq` selecionar qual deseja, segue exemplo

```
public class Carro//Classe
{
    public int CarroId { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
}

public static class Service//Service, utilizada para criar o metodo que irá retornar 
{
    public static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(object obj)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declara novo objeto
        Carro car = new Carro
        {
            CarroId = 1,
            Modelo = "Fiesta",
            Marca = "Ford"
        };

        //Pega o array de todas propriedades do objeto carro
        var properties = Service.GetProperties(car);

        //Atributo
        var atributo = "Modelo";

        //Seleciona o valor do atributo pelo nome, utilizando linq
        var atributoSelecionado = properties.Where(p => p.Name == atributo).FirstOrDefault().GetValue(car,null);

        //foreach para varrer todas propriedades e pegar o nome e valor de cada uma
        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            string name = p.Name;
            var value = p.GetValue(car, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Também coloque no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ISlLJz) para referencia

Answer (score 0):

Através de reflection

```
string atributo = "modelo"
string conteudo = meuCarro.GetType().GetProperty(atributo).GetValue(meuCarro);
```